# How do I query multiple symbol in one field in kdb?

Tags: kdb

How do I select specific records if i only put one symbol in filter?

```
Eg:
tab:([]a:1 2 3;b:(`abc`bde;`efg`rte;`dqw`gds))
1   (`abc`bde)
2   (`efg`rte)
3   (`dqw`gds)
```

I want to filter on `abc` so only return:

```
1   (`abc`bde)
```

`` select from tab where b=`abc `` will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query KDB table where one column is a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090753/how-to-query-kdb-table-where-one-column-is-a-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the each-right adverb `/:` with the `in` function:

```
q)select from tab where `abc in/: b
a b      
---------
1 abc bde
```

Each-right is necessary here because table columns are vectors; so `in` is operating on a *nested* list of symbols. The `exec` call below shows this more clearly:

```
q)0N!(exec b from tab);
(`abc`bde;`efg`rte;`dqw`gds)
```